# Toggle model visibility dynamically at runtime

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

Currently loading Multiple models in forge viewer, is there any way to hide/show one or two models at runtime based on user input?

Answer (score 0):

It's straightforward. Just to call `hideModel` or `showModel` when needed.

```
const models = viewer.getAllModels();

// Hide the model
viewer.hideModel( models[0] )

// Show the model
viewer.showModel( models[0] )
```

ref:

- https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/GuiViewer3D/#showmodel-model-preservetools
- https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#hidemodel-model